# Referencing variables before assignment?

Tags: solidity

Is it good practice to reference variables before assignment in Solidity? I'm noticing this in a contract I am reading and I'm trying to make sense of how this works. I read about variable hoisting, but it seems that is more relevant to variables referenced/declared within functions.

The particular example I'm looking at can be found [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-complete-guide-to-building-an-ethereum-dapp-1692976ec4a5) and the specific variable is `keyHash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good practice in this, but you need to understand how variables work. For example, state variables, those that will be permanent on the blockchain, must be declared outside of functions. So, if you need to store a variable, but you just will have its value through a function, you'll have to declare it before the functions. If it is a constant variable and you already know it in advance, you can directly declare its value or, declare the empty variable in advance, and indicate the value in the constructor. It makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks! I understand how state vs memory variables work, that all makes sense to me. What I'm confused about is this code: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MichaelMacaulay/ed9c97e217f24654daec5dde6b92b86f/raw/d9693caaa95cbb06af3ee0709e2a346c13980424/EtherCoinFlip.sol. I found it online and it looks like the variable `keyHash` is declared after being used in a function. That doesn't make sense to me, and I was wondering if that is acceptable to do in Solidity.

Comment: Ah, okay. Solidity is a typed language, so you MUST declare the type of the variables before assign a value to it. In the example you show, apparently they haven't declared keyHash before its use, but it was certainly declared in some parent contract of this contract. See that the example contract inherit variables of another contract, which in turn can be heir to other contracts. Somewhere in the "contracts tree of parents" this variable has been declared. You can follow the white rabbit to check it =)

Comment: Ah awesome! thank you, that makes perfect sense, so always must declare before reference. Thanks so much!

Comment: It doesn't look like a parent contract declared that variable :(. I checked here https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol, and also in the contract that one inherited from. Maybe its because keyHash is declared in the constructor? This still doesn't make sense to me, and my linter tells me that the declaration is on like #46 (below the constructor). So now I'm really confused

Comment: Check the documentation at https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html. It says "Solidity is a statically typed language, which means that the type of each variable (state and local) needs to be specified. Solidity provides several elementary types which can be combined to form complex types."

Comment: I never used an oracle contract, so I don't know where to declare this variable, but it must be declared somewhere.